# resource rutas en ruby on rails 7 no asigna controlador articles#index a articles_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy comenzando en rails, entiendo que resource crea rutas segun cierta convencion. Muestro mi codigo y explico el problema. Tengo el siguiente controlador:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_article, except: [:new,:create,:update,:index,:from_author]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new,:create,:edit,:destroy]

  def index
    @articles= Article.all
  end

  def from_author
    @user= User.find(params[:user_id])
    # render json: @user.email
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article= Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article= current_user.articles.create(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
    # render json: @article
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other
  end

  def find_article
    @article= Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title,:content)
  end

end
```

y este es mi archivo de rutas:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  root to: "home#index"


  resource :articles do
  get 'user/:user_id', to: 'articles#from_author', on: :collection
  end
  

end
```

Con este codigo espero que la ruta `articles_path` se ha `/articles` y apunte hacia `articles#index`. Lamentablemente eso no pasa, mas bien `articles_path` esta apuntando a `articles#show`, no se por que pasa eso, gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Estoy usando rails 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando [`resource`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) en vez de[`resources`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web).
Tu ruta debería ser:

```
  resources :articles do
    get 'user/:user_id', to: 'articles#from_author', on: :collection
  end
```